# How to position infoWindow on my map?

Tags: android, dictionary, positioning, infowindow

I have a `RelativeLayout` that holds some views.
One of the views is `MapView`, basically a view that renders bitmap in a canvas.

Now I would like to implement some sort of information window.

I have created an layout for it with a `FrameLayout` holding a `TextView`. I used 9patch on the image so its stretchable to hold any content.

I have implemented gesture (long press) on my `MapView` and I know the screen point where the `infoWindow` should be visible. Then I tried inflating the info window view and position it somehow ... but the problem is I cant measure it (the values are 0), so I have no idea how to position it over my map.

Any tip how to position my info window would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i moved the map, getting the selected location on the center and i inflate the info windows always on the center.